# Apache2 virtual host not working. "DNS adress cant be found"

Tags: server, apache2, virtualhost

Trying to add a virtual host `test.mysite.se`. I've followed all the steps here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

I didnt encouter any problems during the setup, but when i try to reach `test.mysite.se` I simply get a DNS error from chrome. But if I simply reach `localhost` i get to my site.

I thought it was wierd for me to add a virtual host in the same folder `var/www` as the other sites. On my windows machine, I set up my virtual host from another folder oustide of this.

Path to my site: `/var/www/test.mysite.se`
Contents of `test.mysite.conf` inside of `etc/apache2/sites-available/`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin blablabla@gmail.com
    ServerName test.mysite.se
    ServerAlias www.test.mysite.se

    DocumentRoot /var/www/test.mysite.se/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I am not quite sure why it isnt working. Should I try to link the path to my page from another place instead of `/var/www` folder?

Comment: Did you set the /etc/hosts files as in the example in the link you provided?

Comment: Yeah, did exactly as in the link. Are you talking about the test.mysite.conf file?

Comment: I'm referring to `/etc/hosts` file

Comment: I have not changed anything in that file. Didnt think I had to since that was for testing only(?). And I am not running this server through an VPS so I dont have an IP which I can add there. Or am i missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Applying following changes may help you.

On your main hosts file [ **/etc/hosts** ]

```
203.95.221.49  www.mysite.se mysite.se test.mysite.se
```

[/etc/hosts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12I2I.jpg)

On your site's conf file [ **/etc/apache2/sites-available/test.mysite.se.conf** ]

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin blablabla@gmail.com
    ServerName test.mysite.se
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test.mysite.se/
</VirtualHost>
```

[test.mysite.se.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAze2.jpg)

Finally add an A record point to the sub domain and IP

```
Type    Host              Value
 A      test.mysite.se    203.95.221.49
```

Thanks.